# How to preserve data between executions of program

Tags: perl, hp-ux

I am running a perl script on a HP-UX box. The script will execute every 15 minutes and will need to compare it's results with the results of the last time it executed.

I will need to store two variables (IsOccuring and ErrorCount) between the executions. What is the best way to do this?

Edit clarification:
It only compares the most recent execution to the current execution.
It doesn't matter if the value is lost between reboots.
And touching the filesystem is pretty much off limits.

Comment: DO you have to keep a historical record of the variables, or just compare against the most recent? That would make the difference between using a csv/xml or a database ;)

Comment: Linux, or HPUX? Two totally different OSs -- although the differences aren't really material here.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: you're saying (1) you can't use the filesystem and also (2) you can't keep the connection open (your answer to @tMC)? If so, I suppose you will want to connect to a database or a file on a different machine (though that strikes me as very ugly).

Comment: There are other ways to store things other than a filesystem or database. I was thinking the best way might be an environment variable, or an IPC shared memory. But I wanted to see what the community thought.

Comment: @Malfist Fair enough I suppose. As far as I know, you can't export environment variables from a Perl program back into the parent environment (at least not without something fairly roundabout).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't touch the file system, try using a shared memory segment. There are helper modules for that like [`IPC::ShareLite`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aShareLite), or you can use the [`shmget`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shmget.html) and related functions directly.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to store them in a file. This sort of file is often kept in `/tmp`, but any place where the user running the cron job has access would do.  Make sure your script can handle the case where the file is missing.

Comment: See update: I'd prefer not to write to the filesystem if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a separate process running a "remember stuff" service over your choice of IPC mechanism. This sounds like a rather tortured solution to "I don't want to touch the disk" but if it's important enough to offset a couple of days of development work (realistically, if you are new to IPC, and HP-SUX continues to live up to its name) then by all means read **man perlipc** for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be completely re-executed? Can you just have it running in a loop and sleeping for 15 minutes between iterations? Than you don't have to worry about saving the values externally, the program never stops.

Comment: @Yatrix, why is it so terrifying?

Comment: Sorry, I meant tMC's. Yours is fine. =)

Comment: @yatrix - sorry, im just SUPER hungry.. thats my 'IM HUNGRY' face.

Comment: By all means, don't let me stop you, dude. Get some food, FAST.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely think IPC is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd save off the data in a file. Then, inside the script I'd load the last results if the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use module [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable/Storable.pm) to serialize Perl data structures, save them anywhere you want and deserialize them during next script execution.